# Cannot Adjust Position of Child UL in Nav Menu

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulty adjusting the position of all child UL's in a navigation ul menu.  I want all the children ul's to be positioned equally from their respective parent li's.  Instead, they all display at different positions when you hover over their parent li.  Some will display directly under their parent as intended, but others tend to display several pixels away from their parent li leaving a weird space [see picture].  This menu is a SharePoint 2013 topnav for the systems masterpage.  I was able to get the topnav for the site masterpage to display like I wanted, however, the system masterpage has a different XHTML/HTML layout in that instead of this:

```
<ul class="parent">
  <li>Category 1
      <ul><li>Link</li>
          <li>Link</li>
       </ul></li>
  <li>Category 2
     <ul><li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
    </ul></li>
 </ul>
```

They are using this:

```
<ul class="parent">
 <li>
   <ul>
      <li>Category 1
          <ul><li>Link 1</li>
              <li>Link 2</li>
           </ul></li>
       <li>Category 2
          <ul><li>Link 1</li>
              <li>Link 2</li>
           </ul></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Not sure why they decided to do that, as it's silly to me, but it's causing me a world of problems in conjunction with the myriad of classes they've assigned to the menu.

Please see my jsfiddle for a look at my current css and the html:

https://jsfiddle.net/of2ek35c/[image]

Comment: No it isn't.  Perhaps an example of what I want would make more sense.  Please see http://www.navantis.com.   I do not want ANY spaces between the parent UL and the submenu, and I want ALL submenus to be positioned the same distance from the parent li.  If you go to 'PMO Collaboration Sites' like in the picture, you see all that white space.   On other li, the submenu overlays the li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. there were a bunch of strange css styles for the submenus ( in addition to the ones you pointed out )

as i know...for the sub-menus, you need to set `position:relative` to the parent `li` and `position:absolute;display:none` to the `ul.sub-menu`

keeping this in mind, i added the following lines to your code

```
.topnav ul ul ul {
    margin:0!important;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
}
.topnav ul li > ul li {
     position:relative;
}
.topnav ul ul li.dynamic-children:hover > ul { 
    display:block;
}
```

see below snippet or > **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/of2ek35c/7/)**

Let me know if it works for you

```css
#menu {width:80%; margin-left:5px; display:flex; height:55px; background:#000}
.topnav ul {list-style-type: none; padding:0; margin:0; margin-left:-25px; text-transform: uppercase; color:#fff!important; text-align: center; height:55px; font:800 0.8em "Raleway"!important;}
.topnav ul li {list-style: none; height: 100%; width: 115px; display:inline;}
.topnav ul li > ul {height:100%; margin:0; position:relative; top:0px;}
.topnav ul li > ul li {display:inline-block; white-space:pre-wrap; font:inherit; margin-right:6px; padding:0; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; height:100%; word-wrap:break-word;position:relative;}
.topnav ul li > ul li:hover > ul {opacity:1;}
.topnav ul li > ul li:hover > ul li {height:20px; overflow:visible; padding:0;}
.topnav ul ul ul {opacity:0; height:auto; margin:0!important; padding:3px; font:inherit!important; display:none; width:135px; background:#010831; border-top:1px solid #121a46; position:absolute; top:100%; left:0;}
.topnav ul ul ul > li {height: 0; overflow:hidden; padding:0;}
.topnav li a {color: #fff;  padding:5px 0px; text-decoration: none;}
.topnav ul ul li.dynamic-children:hover > ul { display:block;}
```

```html
<nav class="topnav" id="menu">
<ul class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static" id="zz13_RootAspMenu">
  <li class="static"><a tabindex="0" class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" accesskey="1" href="/ecms/pages/home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="static">
      <li class="static selected"><a tabindex="0" title="ECMS Home" class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-bold ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/pages/home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Home</span><span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span></span></a></li>
      <li class="static dynamic-children"><span tabindex="0" title="Final Navy EBS Documentation" class="static dynamic-children menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="menu-item-text">Final Navy EBS Documentation</span></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="dynamic" style="margin-top: 10px; z-index: 1100;">
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="PMW220 Documents" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/FinalDocuments/Forms/Navy EBS Documents.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">PMW220 Documents</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="ePS Final Approved Documents" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/FinalDocuments/Forms/ePS Documents.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">ePS Documents</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Click to open Navy ERP Final Approved Documents" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/FinalDocuments/Forms/Navy ERP Documents.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Navy ERP Documents</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Click to open Final Approved SLDCADA Documents" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/FinalDocuments/Forms/SLDCADA Documents.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">SLDCADA Documents</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="static dynamic-children"><span tabindex="0" title="Product Line Sites" class="static dynamic-children menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="menu-item-text">Product Line Sites</span></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="dynamic" style="z-index: 1100;">
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="ePS" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/eps/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Navy ePS</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Navy ERP" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/erp/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Navy ERP</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="eBusiness" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/ebus"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">eBusiness</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="static dynamic-children"><span tabindex="0" title="PMO Collaboration Sites" class="static dynamic-children menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="menu-item-text">PMO Collaboration Sites</span></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="dynamic" style="z-index: 1100;">
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Acquisition Management" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/am/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Acquisition Management</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Audit Readiness" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/ar/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Audit Readiness</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Business Finance" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/bfm/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Business Finance</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Configuration Management" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/cm/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Configuration Management</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Corporate Operations" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/co/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Corporate Operations</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Cyber Security" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/cs/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Cyber Security</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Enterprise Architecture" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/ea/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Enterprise Architecture</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Front Office" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/frontoffice"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Front Office</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Interface Management" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/im/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Interface Management</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Program Control" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/pc/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Program Control</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Product Support" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/ps/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Product Support</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Enterprise Engineering" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/ee/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Systems Engineering</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Technical Director" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/td"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Technical Director</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Test and Evaluation" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/te/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Test and Evaluation</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="static dynamic-children"><span tabindex="0" title="Service Provider Collaboration Sites" class="static dynamic-children menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="menu-item-text">Service Provider Collaboration Sites</span></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="dynamic" style="z-index: 1100;">
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Enterprise Integration" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/ei/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Enterprise Integration</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Enterprise Operations" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/eo/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Enterprise Operations</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="eBusiness Suite Technical Teams" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/ebustech"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">eBusiness Suite Technical Teams</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="static dynamic-children"><span tabindex="0" class="static dynamic-children menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="menu-item-text">Program Tools</span></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="dynamic" style="z-index: 1100;">
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/adc/SitePages/Dashboard2.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Audit PBC Requests</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Conference Room Calendars" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/Pages/Conference-Rooms.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Conference Room Calendars</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="ECMS Service Requests" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/requests"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Master Roster" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/Lists/Master Roster"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Master Roster</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/Lists/Program Calendar/calendar.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Navy EBS Calendar</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/search/Pages/PAL.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Process Asset Library</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/docPacket/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Document Routing</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="static dynamic-children"><span tabindex="0" title="Working Groups" class="static dynamic-children menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="menu-item-text">Working Groups</span></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="dynamic" style="z-index: 1100;">
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="Audit War Room" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/AWR/default.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Audit War Room</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" title="ePS Procurement IPT" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/IPT"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">ePS Procurement IPT</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/erpupgrade/default.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Navy ERP 2017 Upgrade</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="static dynamic-children"><span tabindex="0" class="static dynamic-children menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="menu-item-text">Dashboards</span></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="dynamic" style="z-index: 1100;">
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/PM/SitePages/Home.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Navy EBS Metrics (Testing)</span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="static dynamic-children"><a tabindex="0" class="static dynamic-children menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/Lists/NAVEBS Acronyms/AllItems.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow dynamic-children" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="menu-item-text">Resources</span></span></a>
        <ul class="dynamic" style="z-index: 1100;">
          <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/Lists/NAVEBS Acronyms/AllItems.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">PMW220 Acronym List</span></span></a></li>
          <li class="dynamic">
            <a tabindex="0" title="This is the End User ECMS Quick Reference Guide." class="dynamic menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/ecms/pc/Working Team Documents/End_User_Quick_Reference.docx?Web=1"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"></span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The most left item doesn't work and the most right one pops to the right so there's a scrollbar.

Comment: I know - SharePoint overkills the class styles.  I actually figured out what it was!  I had to add an !important to the 'position:absolute' tag because SharePoint actually adds this random class called 'hover' which makes everything relative.  What a headache..  thank you for your help!

Comment: @g3mini the most left item doesn't have submenu , for the most right item, you should check on the correct screen size ( the `li's` have a fixed width )

@user2004758 glad i could help. i know SharePoint is a pain in the a** :)

Comment: It does seem to have a submenu when I move my mouse down though. Something does pop up with some spacing between the menu.

Comment: yep because `#menu` has `background-color:#000` but has a fixed height of `55px` . that's why i said you need to check on the correct screen size. It's SharePoint :) strange things happen